# Preventing .ajaxError for being called if handled elsewhere

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I have a global `$(document).ajaxError` handler that takes care of most errors for me just in case there is ever an unexpected 500 error or something.  However, there are times when I want to catch errors locally in a script and then prevent that global error handler from being called.  Is there a way to do this such as you would with an event.stopPropagation()?

Example

```
$.get('/something/', function() {
    alert("Stuff went well.");
}).error(function(response)) {
    if (response.status == 404) {
        alert('Page not found');
        // Do something to stop global ajaxError from being called.
    }
});
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to pass the `global: false` param to `$.ajax` like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/something/',
    global: false,
    success: function() {
       alert('Success');
    }
}).error(function(response)) {
    if (response.status == 404) {
        alert('Page not found');
    }
});
```

Reference: [Ajax Events](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax_Events), [jQuery.get](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)